# Xcode 10.1 build error, library not found for -lRNGoogleSignin

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am trying to build my `react-native` project in xcode, I have recently removed the `googleSignIn` `node_module`, cleaned my build and ran `npm cache verify`. I keep getting the above error.

Any ideas?

I am using `react-native v0.57.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Check any reference to that module in Xcode `libraries` and Linked `frameworks and libraries`**

[image]
[image]

and remove them.

For faster results take a quick look in ios folder and locate the file `project.pbxproj` search for any reference in that file and remove it.

**2) Also check pod file and make sure you have no reference to that module in there.**

Note:

To clean the cache you can run something like this:
`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

(If you don't have yarn you can use npm)